# How to prove the limit of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a real sequence $a_1 = \frac{4}{5}$ with $a_{n + 1} = \frac{a_n}{3} + 1$.

I have proved that $a_n \le \frac{3}{2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I also proved that $a_{n + 1} \ge a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Combining these two facts, we have that a monotonically increasing sequence, bounded above converges.

I would like to find the limit. I propose (through observation) it is $\frac{3}{2}$.

How can I prove this? I have the definition of convergence, triangle inequalities, and also the fact that $\sup \{a_n : n \ge 1 \}$ is the limit. I have no other tools at my disposal.

I've tried many diferent things, but I continue to get nowhere.

Here are some things I've tried:

- showing $\frac{3}{2}$ is the least upper bound
- using the definition + triangle inequalities to prove $\frac{3}{2}$ is the limit

Comment: Let the sequence converge to $a$. Then $a=\frac{a}{3}+1$, which means that $a=\frac32$.

Comment: Write $a_n=1+\frac{1}{3}a_{n-1}$ and calculate $a_2$, $a_3$, $\ldots$. Then, try to write $a_n$ in a closed form and try to find the limit with a telescope sum trick.

Comment: I wrote the tools I have at my disposal in the problem. I don’t know what you mean with your trick. It needs to be a neat, clean proof by the definition or with the supremum trick I mentioned @user408858

Comment: You could also show that $a_n=\frac32-\frac{21}{10}\left(\frac13\right)^n$. Since $-1<\frac13<1$, $\left(\frac13\right)^n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so $a_n\rightarrow\frac32$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first method you mentioned? @SaiMehta

Comment: You have proven that the sequence does converge, which means that each term in the sequence keeps getting closer and closer to that limit. We can therefore say that once we are at that limit, the next term in the sequence is the same as the last one, and so $a_{n+1}=a_n=\frac{a_n}{3}+1$, which leads to $a_n=\frac32$.

Comment: We don't know that we ever reach the limit (we could just always be approaching it) @SaiMehta and I don't see your logic from the definition of the limit.

Comment: They are using the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}$ whenever it exists. So, if $a$ is the limit, then $a = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n / 3 + 1 = (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n) / 3 + 1 = a/3+1$.

Comment: Thanks @JairTaylor . So $a = a/3 + 1$ and it is trivial from there. Where does the fact you mentioned come from? I don’t know if I have it.

Comment: NP. I don't have a particular reference - I'd try proving it yourself as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

By observation

$$a_n=1+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}a_1$$

Therefore

$$(1-\frac{1}{3})a_n=1+\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}a_1-\frac{1}{3^{n}}a_1=1+\frac{2a_1}{3^n}$$

and

$$(1-\frac{1}{3})\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{3})a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{2a_1}{3^n})=1+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2a_1}{3^n}=1$$

This yields
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Note, that $a_n=1+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}a_1$ can be proven by induction, if you do not trust the observation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

$$u_{n+1}=f(u_n), ~u_1=4/5$$

with $f(x) = \frac{x}{3}+1$. You have also that $f$ is contractant, i.e.,

$$\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |f(x)-f(y)| = \frac{1}{3}|x-y|.$$

With the [Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), you have that the sequence has a limit $u^*$ that is the unique fixed-point of $f$. This fixed-point can be computed as:

$$u^* = f(u^*) \iff u^* = 3/2.$$

This theorem is very useful for proving and finding the limit of a sequence. The proof is quite easy to understand if you want to have a look!

Comment: Banach theorem? Did you read my question! I specifically stated what is at my disposal.

Comment: You are welcome, if you read carefully the proof of this theorem (that you could apply here), it uses only triangular inequality.